# no responce when using devise in other controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm not so long in Rails development and now am working with checkout login logic. I ended up with finding this kind of solution in order to pass user as the resource for using Devise in other controllers

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end
 
  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def resource_class
    User
  end
 
  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

Though I now can use resourse in my controller, when I'm trying to login/sign up Devise doesn't work properly. I get error of incorrect email/password when I'm trying to log in and get no response trying to sign up. Even if I leave email field empty I don't receive error which should appear due to resource.errors.

My code is:

```
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  = render 'devise/shared/error_messages', resource: resource
    = f.label :email, 'Enter Email'
    = f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Enter Email'
    = resource.errors.messages[:email].to_sentence
    = f.submit ''
```

Maybe anyone else had the same problem or saw any solution in such situation, I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a user and then pass them to other functions, if they successfully log in, you can use `current_user` as per the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise)

But I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. The user should be @user or :user, depending on your setup. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What are the other controllers like?

Comment: I used this recommendations for creating guest users https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user and I guess this is a thing that breaks registration. I already solved the problem with logging in yet the registration is still a problem for me. Still, when I sign up in Devise generated view, everything works properly, but when I try to do it in checkout controller method recieves current_user = nil and skips the registration